# How can I change the position of an object through the ccp function in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to the cocos2d framework, so I took the sample application from [this location](http://www.raywenderlich.com/downloads/Cocos2DSimpleGame.zip) and tried to modify it.  By using the line

```
target.position = ccp(winSize.width , (target.contentSize.width/2)+actualY);
```

the object is shown in landscape.  When the app runs it will show me the output in landscape mode, and the targets are shown from the starting the landscape mode of one side to another side.  I want to show it from the the end of the landscape mode to the start.  How can I do this?

Also, I want to show in portrait mode. How can I do this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok use ccp function. the body will be like this. ccp(x, y)

Answer (score 0):

OK, cpp function means the same as CGPointMake(x,y) - only creates a point for position of target.

winSize.width - will be xcoordinate of target, and
(target.contentSize.width/2)+actualY - ycoordinate

Comment: I know this function, but the problem is that my brother I want to show this object randomly through portrait mode, what changes I have to do for it??

Answer (score 0):

What version of cocos2d u using? You can change orientation of app in the app delegate.. From landscape to portrait..

Answer (score 0):

ok I solve that problem, I simply change the position of x and y through ccp function